# Angular2: jit_unwrapValue12(...) is undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using a `Subject` in order to show a component:

```
private componentsState$: BehaviorSubject<{[key: string]: boolean}> = 
   new BehaviorSubject(this.getFormComponentState());
```

I've several components:

```
private swapComponent(componentName: string): void {
  let componentsState = {
    'list': (): void => this.componentsState$.next(this.getListComponentState()),
    'form': (): void => this.componentsState$.next(this.getFormComponentState()),
    'detail': (): void => this.componentsState$.next(this.getDetailComponentState()),
  };

  componentsState[componentName]();
}
```

So, in order to change the state among the component or emit a value:

```
private getListComponentState(): {[key: string]: boolean} {
  return { list: true, form: false, detail: false};
}

private getFormComponentState(): {[key: string]: boolean} {
  return { list: false, form: true, detail: false};
}

private getDetailComponentState(): {[key: string]: boolean} {
  return { list: false, form: false, detail: true};
}
```

And on template:

```
<div *ngIf="(componentsState$ | async)?.list" payment-list></div>
<div *ngIf="(componentsState$ | async)?.form" payment-form></div>
<div *ngIf="(componentsState$ | async)?.detail" payment-detail></div>
```

However, sometimes I'm getting an error like this:

> ERROR TypeError: jit_unwrapValue12(...) is undefined

Stacktrace:

```
[object Object]  PaymentList.ngfactory.js:109:6
    View_PaymentList_1 ng:///PaymentModule/PaymentList.ngfactory.js:109:6
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js"]/</DebugContext_.prototype.logError
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js"]/</ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js"]/</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone/</<.next
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js"]/</EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js"]/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js"]/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js"]/Subscriber.prototype._next
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js"]/Subscriber.prototype.next
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js"]/Subject.prototype.next
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js"]/</EventEmitter.prototype.emit
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js"]/</NgZone.prototype.triggerError
    ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js"]/</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onHandleError
    ac_polyfills<["./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"]/</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.handleError
    ac_polyfills<["./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"]/</</Zone.prototype.runTask
    ZoneTask/this.invoke
```

Any ideas?